# Jsoup - How to tell if an HTML string is a complete page or a fragment?

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

I couldn't find a method which can tell if a string input is a complete HTML page or just a fragment (without `<html><body> ... </body></html>`).
I looked at the jsoup implementation and found the implementations of parse and parseBodyFragment but not a method which decides which of them to use according to a string.

An example for a complete HTML (needs normal parse):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <h1>My First Heading</h1>
   <p>My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

An example for an HTML fragment (needs parseBodyFragment) :

```
<div style=\"color:#0000FF\"> 
  <h3>This is a heading</h3>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Since all `html`, `head` and `body` elements can be omitted, the difference between a complete page and a fragment is minimal. The presence of a doctype, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Jsoup.parse` will look for head and body elements and nest them properly in the html tag.  `Jsoup.parseBodyFragment` will place everything within the body tag.  Either way, a complete HTML document will be created.  If you are unsure about whether your input is full or fragment, use parse.

Consider this fragment with head elements.

```
    <title>my title</title>
    <div style="color:#0000FF">
        <h3>This is a heading</h3>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    </div>
```

---

Using parse

```
    System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(fragment).html());
```

Output:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>my title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div style="color:#0000FF"> 
   <h3>This is a heading</h3> 
   <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Note the properly nested `<title>` in the `<head>`.

---

Using parseBodyFragment

```
    System.out.println(Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(fragment).html());
```

Output

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <title>my title</title>
  <div style="color:#0000FF"> 
   <h3>This is a heading</h3> 
   <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Note the improperly nested `<title>` in the `<body>`.

---

> My question is how to recognize if my input is a fragment or not. Not
>   what parse and parseBodyFragment methods do. Because if I have a
>   fragment, I want to parse it without adding body tags (leave it as
>   is).

Jsoup will normalize the content into an HTML document.  However, you can use W3C dom and javax.xml.parsers, which are both in the JRE.  You can check if the first node is HTML or not.

```
import javax.swing.text.html.HTML.Tag;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

...

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); 
    Document doc = db.parse(myInputStream);
    Node root = doc.getFirstChild();
    boolean isFragment = !root.getNodeName().equals(Tag.HTML.toString());
```

Comment: My question is how to recognize if my input is a fragment or not. Not what parse and parseBodyFragment methods do. Because if I have a fragment, I want to parse it without adding body tags (leave it as is).